# Default language of the application is not set

Tags: ios, swift, localization, xcodegen

I need to set the default Russian language in the application to swift.
I am using Xcodegen to generate .xcodeproj.
There is my project.yml

```
options:
  deploymentTarget: '13.0'
  groupSortPosition: top
  generateEmptyDirectories: true
  minimumXcodeGenVersion: '2.32.0'
  developmentLanguage: ru
```

After generation, Russian is displayed as default

[image]
In app delegate I call this function:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        LanguageManager.shared.firstLaunchCurrentLanguageSetup()
...
```

```
final class LanguageManager {
    static let shared = LanguageManager()
    
    var selected: String {
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.set([newValue, selected], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "language")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            setLanguage()
        }
        get {
            return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "language") ?? LanguagesList.russianCode
        }
    }
    func firstLaunchCurrentLanguageSetup() {
        if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "language") != nil {
            return
        } else {
            selected = LanguagesList.russianCode
        }
    }
private func setLanguage() {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("LanguageDidChange"), object: nil)
    }
}

struct LanguagesList {
    static let englishCode = "en"
    static let russianCode = "ru"
    
    static let languages: [String: String] = [
        englishCode: "English",
        russianCode: "Русский"
    ]
}
```

Info.plist:
[image]

After all these manipulations, when the application is first launched, it still runs in English on the device with the English language set, and when repeated, it is already in Russian. I also need to run it in Russian at the first launch

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to comment so I posted an answer here.

Please Add `setLanguage()` function in your question

Or

You can check/Add below code in your `setLanguage()` function

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(["ru"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
defaults.synchronize()
Bundle.setLanguage("ru")
```

Comment: edited. I use setLanguage to send notification

Comment: Add these 4 lines in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and check.